# Create a plugin to display modified content in full page body in joomla

Tags: php, android, plugins, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to display Download Android App message(An image) to users browsing from Android device. For that i have created a content plugin but it is not working properly. It is showing Message to desktop users as well and only at the place of article content. I want to display this image in full page body and no other content(like headers,menus,footer,sidebars) should be displayed other than it.I am a newbie to joomla development so please help.

here's my androidmsg.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgcontentandroidmsg extends JPlugin {
    function __construct(&$subject, $params) {
        parent::__construct($subject, $params);
    }
    function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $offset = 0) {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        if ($app->isAdmin()) {
            return;
        }
        $title = &$article->title;
        $text = &$article->text;
        $uri = JFactory::getURI();
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            if (stripos($ua, 'android') !== false) {

                if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
                    $app->redirect($uri);
                } else {
                    $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                    setcookie("user", "app_android", $expire);
                    $text = '<div><img src="'. JPATH_BASE .'/abc/abc.png"/></div>';
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tested this code with a simple `echo` and it's works fine. What version of Android are you testing on? And which browser on Android?

Comment: Hey @Lodder, i am testing it on Android 4.2.2 with firefox browser. It is working for Android but when i am testing it from my pc(win 7 - chrome) it is also showing the message. And i want to display this image in full webpage, my site is [here](http://test.guru99.com)

Comment: I think it might be due to the plugin event (`onContentPrepare`) you are using but am not 100% sure. It might be an idea to detect Android using an event that get's fired before the framework is loaded, such as `onBeforeRender`.

Comment: Hey @Lodder, Thanks for the suggestion. I have done it with onAfterRender event, but it is showing me 'headers already sent error' now. Warning: Cannot modify header information-headers already sent by(output started at /home/gurutest/public_html/components/com_invitex/helper.php:1) in /home/gurutest/public_html/plugins/system/androidmsg/androidmsg.php on line 32
my updated code is [here](http://screencast.com/t/twAk0YJ6gXRi)

Comment: @Lodder, I want to display this message only once so i set a cookie and check it's value but it is showing message everytime and cookie doesn't set code 
`$cookieName = 'mymsgseen';`

`$cookieValue = $app->input->cookie->get($cookieName);`

`if ($cookieValue!=null && $cookieValue==1) {`

`$htmlString = 'cookie is set : '.$cookieValue;`

`$app->setBody($htmlString);`

`} else {`

`$cookieValue=1;`

`$expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;`

`$app->input->cookie->set($cookieName, $cookieValue, $expire);`

`}`

Comment: May I suggest you post this question on http://joomla.stackexchange.com ;)